# How to enable CORS in python

Tags: python-2.7, cors

Let me start this with, I do not know python, I've had maybe 1 day going through the python tutorials.  The situation is this.  I have an angular app that has a python app hosted with Apache on a vm in an iframe.  I didn't write the python app, but another developer wrote me an endpoint where I am supposed to be able to post from my angular app.

The developer who made the python endpoint is saying that there is something wrong with my request but I am fairly certain there isn't anything wrong.  I am almost 100% certain that the problem is that there are no CORS headers in the response and/or the response is not set up to respond to the OPTIONS method.  Below is the entirety of the python endpoint:

```
import os, site, inspect
site.addsitedir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))+"/../")
import json
from datetime import datetime

import pymongo

from Config import Config


def application(environ, start_response):
  response = environ['wsgi.input'].read(int(environ['CONTENT_LENGTH']))

  if response:
    json_response = json.loads(response)

    document = {
      'payment_id': json_response['payment_id'],
      'log': json_response['log'],
      'login_id': json_response['login_id'],
      'browser': environ.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', None),
      'ip_address': environ.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None),
      'created_at': datetime.utcnow(),
    }

    client = pymongo.MongoClient(Config.getValue('MongoServer'))
    db = client.updatepromise
    db.PaymentLogs.insert(document)

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    return '{"success": true}'

  start_response('400 Bad Request', [('Content-Type', 'application/json')])
  return '{"success": false}'
```

I have attempted the following to make this work:  I added to both start_response functions more headers so the code looks like this now:

```
start_response('201 OK', [('Content-Type', 'application/json',
  ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','authorization'),
  ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'),
  ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*'),
  ('Access-Control-Max-Age','600'))])
```

Not: I did this both with the 200 and the 400 response at first, and saw no change at all in the response, then just for the heck of it, I decided to change the 200 to a 201, this also did not come through on the response so I suspect this code isn't even getting run for some reason.

Please help, python newb here.

Addendum, i figured this would help, here is what the Headers look like in the response:

```
General:

Request URL: http://rpc.local/api/payment_log_api.py
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.1.20.233:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:

Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/x-python
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 15:18:55 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Request Headers:

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: rpc.local
Origin: http://10.1.20.61:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is.  Just add this to the application right at the beginning:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
  if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS':
    start_response(
      '200 OK',
      [
        ('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, Content-Type'),
        ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'),
      ]
    )
    return ''
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python with CGI, I found this to work:

```
print '''Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n''',
print '''Content-Type: text/html\r\n'''
```

Don't forget to enable CORS on the other side as well, e.g., JavaScript jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({ url: URL, 
             type: "GET", 
             crossDomain: true, 
             dataType: "text", etc, etc
```