# how to configure Access-Control-Allow-Origin using js

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have created a local host using python 2.0, now i'm trying to access a local file using ajax :

```
read.open("POST", "http://localhost:8000/text.txt", true);
read.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
read.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
read.send('http://localhost:8000');
```

the file i'm want to access is text file

but i keep getting these error in chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/text.txt. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response
>   had HTTP status code 501.

and these in firefox

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/text.txt. (Reason: CORS
>   header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

i have looked at few answers which are

1. adding a extension - which is not very helpful if i'm using other browsers.
2. disabling security features in chrome - not a permanent solution.
3. Jquery plugin.

Can anyone tell me any solution that will work for JavaScript?

Comment: CORS should be handled on server side and it should permit the requests from another origin. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065875/how-to-enable-cors-in-python

Comment: The header must be set by the *server*.

Comment: You have to check on your sever side if the .txt is allowed origin.

Comment: It's a security feature designed to stop your JavaScript from reading someone else's data without permission. It would be pretty pointless if your JavaScript could give itself permission to read someone else's data!!

Comment: "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" is set by the server. Which basically means that server is allowing the request from all origin. i.e. After you set this header the XHR request can be made from any domain i.e. eg: xyz.com or abc.com. Also, you might want to check whether your server allows static resource service. I am not aware how did you set up your server so cannot explain further without more information.

Comment: i'm completely aware that
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com/` must be added to the server , just don't know how to add it..

Comment: @AkashJain — So ask a question about the Python HTTP framework you are using. Better yet: Google it.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework (and if you're completely aware of that, why did you ask questions about doing it in client side JavaScript?!)

Comment: @Quentin it's pure python , `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
i was hoping to access using java Script , seems that's not the case anymore

Comment: SimpleHTTPServer is Simple. You need something smarter to do CORS.

Comment: any suggestions???

Comment: Almost anything