# Post request works with python but not javascript/react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I setup an API endpoint for post requests using python, AWS Lambda and API Gateway. I tested the API endpoint using python and everything worked correctly. I tested the same endpoint using javascript and it does not work.

Here is the python script I am running that works correctly.

```
import json
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Data that is posted to API
    data = {"var1" : "x",
            "var2" : 500,
            "var3" : [{"name": "Bob", "age": 22}]}
    
    # Convert dict to json
    data = json.dumps(data) 

    # API endpoint
    url = "https://api.example.com/endpont"

    # POST request
    response = requests.post(url, json=data)

    data = response.text
```

Now I am trying to use the API endpoint in a React app with axios. I am also using a heroku proxy server.

```
function postData() {

    let data = JSON.stringify({
      var1:"x",
      var2:500,
      var3:[{"name": "Bob", "age": 22}]
    })
    const resp = axios.post("https://example.herokuapp.com/https://api.example.com/endpont", data)
  }
```

When I run the axios post request, it doesn't work and gives me this error info:

```
Uncaught in promise - Request failed with status code 502 - ERR_BAD_RESPONSE - Bad Gateway
```

Any ideas what would cause this to work with python but not in javascript?

I tried checking the Heroku proxy server logs for errors and everything appeared normal. I checked the AWS Cloud Watch logs for the Lambda function, but the javascript post request is not even triggering a log entry. When I run the post request with python, a Cloud Watch log entry appears and shows as working correctly.

Comment: Did you mean to have this as your URL in the JavaScript example? "https://example.herokuapp.com/https://api.example.com/endpont"

Comment: I'm not able to post the real endpoint I'm using because the endpoint contains confidential data. So I posted this example URL which is formatted in the same way as the real one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there could be a problem with the proxy server and
[`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) on the server-side. Where the tests are run, (e.g.: the same host as the server), will change how each test is affected by the `CORS` restrictions. HTTP `502` responses might mean it's `CORS` that's the root problem.

- > HTTP response [`502 Bad Gateway`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) server error response code indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from the upstream server.
- > Try using
  > [`cURL`](https://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/ssen/src/curl-7.11.1/docs/curl.html)
  > or
  > [`wGet`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html)
  > to test from multiple environments, (like a development system or a different server).
- > Try debugging the connection from the Heroku proxy server to AWS Lambda.
- > See: [How to enable CORS in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065875/how-to-enable-cors-in-python).

---

##### [dJango](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/):

> Configure the middleware’s behavior in your Django settings. You must set at least one of the following settings:
>
> ```python
> CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS
> ```
>
> If True, all origins will be allowed. Other settings restricting allowed origins will be ignored. Defaults to False.
> Setting this to True can be dangerous, as it allows any website to make cross-origin requests to yours. Generally you’ll want to restrict the list of allowed origins with `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` or `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`.
>
> or
>
> A list of origins that are authorized to make cross-site HTTP requests. The origins in this setting will be allowed, and the requesting origin will be echoed back to the client in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.
>
> ```python
> CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
>    "https://example.com",
>    "https://sub.example.com",
>    "http://localhost:8080",
>    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
> ]
> ```

---

##### [Flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Cors/):

> Simple Usage
>
> In the simplest case, initialize the Flask-Cors extension with default arguments in order to allow `CORS` for all domains on all routes. See the full list of options in the documentation.
>
> ```python
> from flask import Flask
> from flask_cors import CORS
>
> app = Flask(__name__)
> CORS(app)
>
> @app.route("/")
> def helloWorld():
>   return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
> ```
>
> Resource specific `CORS`
>
> Alternatively, you can specify `CORS` options on a resource and origin level of granularity by passing a dictionary as the resources option, mapping paths to a set of options. See the full list of options in the documentation.
>
> ```python
> app = Flask(__name__)
> cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
>
> @app.route("/api/v1/users")
> def list_users():
>   return "user example"
> ```
>
> Route specific `CORS` via decorator
>
> This extension also exposes a simple decorator to decorate flask routes with. Simply add `@cross_origin()` below a call to Flask’s `@app.route(..)` to allow `CORS` on a given route. See the full list of options in the decorator documentation.
>
> ```python
> @app.route("/")
> @cross_origin()
> def helloWorld():
>   return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
> ```

Comment: I enabled CORS in AWS API Gateway and everything is working now. Thanks Nyctfall!

Comment: @WesleyLaurence Glad it worked! CORS configuration is usually the culprit for many API and request errors (when everything _should_ just work), so it's always good to keep an eye out for it when working with APIs.