# MongoDB integrated with React

Tags: python, reactjs, node.js, mongodb

React application connected with Backend using python. Fetching dropdown data from database. Below is the ui code-

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLocations =  () => {
      try {
        const response =  fetch('http://localhost:8000/locations');
        const data = response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setLocations(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching locations:', error);
      }
    };

    const fetchQualifications = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/qualifications');
        const data = await response.json();
        setQualifications(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching qualifications:', error);
      }
    };
  })
```

```
  @app.route('/submit-form', methods=['POST'])
    def submit_form():
        data = request.json 
        print(data)
        collection.insert_one({
        'name': data.get('name', ''),
        'age': data.get('age', 0),
        'location': data.get('location', ''),
        'qualification': data.get('qualification', '')
    })
        return jsonify({'message': 'Form data submitted successfully!'}), 201
```

server is running. In the url i am ale to see the data in json format. Issue is related to front end where i am not getting the data.
Error in console - `GET http://localhost:5000/qualifications net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)`

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your front-end service address port (3000) and back-end service address port(8000) are different, it triggers the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) error.
You would need to see how to enable CORS from your Python API.

[How to enable CORS in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50065875/how-to-enable-cors-in-python)
check if this helps

Comment: Thankyou i got it. Now Post method is not sending data in database